# Keyboard volume slider doesn't connect to correct PulseAudio sink

Tags: sound, keyboard, xubuntu, pulseaudio

I've been searching online to figure out how to tie my keyboard (Logitech Gaming Keyboard G110) volume slider to the "Built-In Analog Audio Stereo" output sink. It defaults to my monitor's sound out, and doesn't switch to another output even after turning off that output device. I'm using Xubuntu 20.04 and PulseAudio version 13.99.1.

Thanks!

Comment: From the Logitech site it states only support for Windows and Mac OS. It may need a driver that does not exist for Linux for some of the features to work.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The headset buttons (deafen and mute) I don't use, and I've never tried the media playback buttons, and the mute key works just fine.

Comment: Like I said SOME.